# AsyncTask error Android App crashes

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

My oncreate code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.board);
    ArrayList<String> passing = new ArrayList<String>();
  new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();


}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "my url here";
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
     public String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        final String[] values = null;
         try {

             // instantiate our json parser
             JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

             // get json string from url
             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

             // get the array of users
             dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("response");

             // loop through all users
             for (int i = 1; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                 JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                 String text = c.getString("text");
                values[i]=text;
             }
          //   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Board.this,R.layout.item, R.id.label, values);
          //   list1.setAdapter(adapter);


         }  
         catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}



 }
```

So, it's starts activity when I comment the section values[i] like this:

```
      //values[i]=text;
```

BUT when it's not commented, app just crashes. I want to doInBackground to return String[] array, how I do that?

Comment: you have `ArrayList<String> passing = new ArrayList<String>();` but where do you use the list? and where is `list1` initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
 values = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];
```

Also note the commented lines are in `doInbackground`. But you can't update ui from a background thread. So the below should go to `onPostExecute`.

```
 //   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Board.this,R.layout.item, R.id.label, values);
 //   list1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Instead of using a `String` array it is better to use a `ArrayList<String>`

You need to change the args type also

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
```

Then

```
 @Override
 public  ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
     try {

         // instantiate our json parser
         JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

         // get json string from url
         JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

         // get the array of users
         dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("response");

         // loop through all users
         for (int i = 1; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

             JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
             String text = c.getString("text");
             values.add(text); 
         }
     }  
     catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return values;
 }
```

Then

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
  super.onPostExecute(result);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Board.this,R.layout.item, R.id.label, result);
   list1.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Also make sure `list1` is initialized before you `setAdapter` to it coz i do not see the code where `list1` is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

you have re declare it again before the for loop

```
values = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];
for (int i = 1; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

             JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
             String text = c.getString("text");
            values[i]=text;
         }
```

you need to reserve its size in the memory by declaring `new`

Answer (score 0):

Just declare String[] array at class level like below,

```
private static String[] array = null;


public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
    String yourJsonStringUrl = "my url here";
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
     public String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        //  final String[] values = null;          
         try {

             // instantiate our json parser
             JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

             // get json string from url
             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

             // get the array of users
             dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("response");

             // loop through all users
             for (int i = 1; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                 JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                 String text = c.getString("text");
                values[i]=text;
             }
          //   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Board.this,R.layout.item, R.id.label, values);
          //   list1.setAdapter(adapter);


         }  
         catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }


         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are creating an `Array` object with to major problem...

1. creating `Array` object without defining it's size.
2. defining as `final` which will not allow you to add new element to that object.

You declaring an `Array` which is `null` and you defining it as `final`. When you declare an `Array` as `final` then you can't change that `Array`. That's why you can't insert new value to that `Array`, as a result, when you are going to access that `Array` its returning `null` value. It's the cause to crash your app.

So, what you have to do is, define the `values` array with a fixed size and don't make it `final`. These will solve your all problem.

Now, replace the following line...

```
final String[] values = null;
```

with these...

```
String[] values;
values = new String[dataJsonArr.length()];
```